# How to automatically trigger intent in schedule time in dialogflow

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am trying to trigger intents in Dialogflow automatically for getting the contact detail of the user in schedule time. please provide the code if it is possible by JavaScript?

Comment: Can you update your question to elaborate on exactly what you're trying to do? It isn't entirely clear what you mean by "getting the contact detail of the user in schedule time". Perhaps you could provide an example conversation with how you want this to look? If you're asking for a JavaScript solution, why have you tagged this "php"? The more information you can provide about what you've tried or what you want this to look like, the better chances we can help you.

Comment: i want to get the name and phone number of user when user chat with chatbot so to get the name and phone number chatbot trigger a question firstly when chatbot open or in every 10sec or 5sec during conversation . if user provide the name and phone number then the chatbot will not ask question for getting details of user

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are multiple ways to achieve this. You can use one of them mentioned below:

1. Create an intent with slot filling. Here how it works
   a. Bot prompt user for name and number and until it gets the required parameter, the intent will not trigger its fulfillment.
   b. Once it has the parameter, fulfillment will trigger your webhook server. where you can save these data in db or chat sessions.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-actions-parameters) you can check how to implement intent with required parameter

2. This is more specific to user who has a google account, you can use authorization in the assistant and request for this information, once user-approved you can get these data.

You can use the helper intent to get the authorization and required data.

```
actions.intent.SIGN_IN
```

[here](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/helpers) you can check all the required helper intent

Comment: i dont want to signin the user . i want that when chatbot start bot ask firstly ask question for getting username and phone number and if the user doesnot give their username and phone number.. the bot will ask question in every 10sec or 5sec

Comment: I am not sure this you can do in Dialogflow directly. This way you can try so the user not provided the details, you can move to the next intent and after completion of it, at the end, you can trigger 'getNameNum' intent with CustomIntentEvent. You can repeate the same at the end of current intent untill user provided details

Answer (score 0):

On Google Actions you can for some devices can use a "No input" response. Your fulfillment service has to provide an array of utterances as shown here: https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/reprompts#actions_sdk

This works for smart speakers but not mobile devices.

If you're using Narratory to author your dialog, this is automatically added for you using localized prompts; https://narratory.io/docs/error-handling#catching-silence--no-input

Comment: where i will place this code https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/reprompts#actions_sdk